# Firestore error: No document to update (in retry method)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of restaurants. I have another collection of menus. I'm using cloud functions and I'm trying to update a document in the restaurant collection whenever a menu is updated. Sometimes when this is happening the restaurant might have been deleted so I'm checking that the document exists before I try to update it. This is the code:

```
export const menuUpdated = functions.firestore.document('menus/{menuId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const menuId = context.params.menuId
    const menuAfter = change.after.data()

    const promises = []
    const promise1 = updateRestaurant(menuAfter.restaurantId)
    promises.push(promise1)

    const promise2 = doSomethingElse()
    promises.push(promise2)

    return Promise.all(promises)
});

async function updateRestaurant(restaurantId: string) {
    try {
        const restaurant = await getRestaurant(restaurantId)
        if (!restaurant) {
            return true
        }

        const ref = db.collection('restaurants/').doc(restaurantId)
        const updateObject = { 'name': 'hello'}
        await ref.update(updateObject)
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        functions.logger.error(error.message)
        return false
    }
}

async function getRestaurant(restaurantId: string) {
    const ref = db.collection('restaurants').doc(restaurantId)
    const doc = await ref.get()
    if (!doc.exists) {
        return null
    }

    const restaurant = doc.data()
    restaurant.documentId = doc.id
    return restaurant
}
```

This is usually working great but sometimes I see errors like this below. This is why I added the check that the document exists before updating but I still see this error:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/XXX/databases/(default)/documents/restaurants/rClGJTKgHq3wv9SDJSDp
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at process.nextTick (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:413:23)
    at DocumentReference.update (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:388:14)
    at updateRestaurant (/workspace/lib/index.js:1166:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 5,
  details:
   'No document to update: projects/XXX/databases/(default)/documents/restaurants/rClGJTKgHq3wv9SDJSDp',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} },
  note:
   'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient' }
```

Can you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How much traffic is this getting? Is it possible that the restaurant is deleted right after you read it, before you update it?

Comment: Yes it could maybe maybe be the issue, if that is the case can I in anyway ignore those errors from being logged? What about the note about "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"?

Comment: Have you solved this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it using a transaction:

```
const ref = db.collection('restaurants').doc(restaurantId);
const updateObject = { 'name': 'hello' };

await db.runTransaction(async transaction => {
    const restaurantSnapshot = await transaction.get(ref);
    if (!restaurantSnapshot.exists) {
        return;
    }
    transaction.update(ref, updateObject);
});
```

I've never done an unsafe `update` in a transaction, so I'm not 100% it will handle the error internally.

If it's still wrong, try `set(updateObject, { merge: true })` instead of `update`.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a good solution but now I get "Error: 10 ABORTED: Aborted due to cross-transaction contention. This occurs when multiple transactions attempt to access the same data, requiring Firestore to abort at least one in order to enforce serializability."

Comment: OK, that seems like good traffic :) I guess the code you posted is greatly simplified. In the code it seems it's OK if the `update` fails. Is that true for the real code? What is the problem exactly? If the problem is the error you're getting in the logs, can't's you just `catch` and ignore it?

Comment: Yes you are right that it is simplified but it is ok that it is failing, not a big issue as this document has already been deleted. I was mostly afraid that there was something strange going on with the error message "Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient" which I didn't understand that is why it didn't feel secure to ignore this. But do you think the issue is that it has already been deleted?

Comment: Sadly I don't really know what that note means.

Comment: Is the "menu" document deleted in the same operation as a "restaurant" is deleted? Maybe the client that's doing that operation isn't performing a batched write, so the menu event is sometimes being processed before the restaurant deletion is applied in the database.

Comment: Yes when the client deletes the restaurant we also have a firebase functions trigger for restaurantDeleted that will delete the menu. When the menu is deleted we have a trigger for menuDeleted that will update some field on restaurant but when that is triggered the restaurant should have already been deleted right? My thinking was it would return on the first if statement in that case? Maybe we need to instead do a batched write on the client but I thought it was cleaner code to use triggers and not have the client have to deal with this?

Comment: Or just ignore the error but the "note" was scary that is why I thought it was good to ask the question :)

Comment: @Martin You can use a different collection (or a document, if the deletion rate is less than 1 per second) to note recently deleted restaurants. In your restaurantDeleted, you would delete the menu AND write the restaurant id (in a batched write), then use that information instead of reading the restaurant document in your check. Then delete the id from the list of ids of recently deleted restaurants.

Comment: @Martin or just do `await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500))` before deleting the menu in the triggered function.

Comment: thanks! You think it would be ok to add that delay maybe that would help?

Comment: @Martin There's one way to find out with certainty :)